# How to get command line arguments in Netbeans IDE 7.0.1?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
package yogita;
public class NewClass7 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     try
      { 
        int n=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int sum=0;
        while(n!=0)
        {
          sum = sum + n%10;
          n=n/10;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
      }
     catch(Exception e){}
   }
}
```

I am using Netbeans IDE 7.0.1 in Windows 8.
Can anyone tell me how can I use command line arguments in this program ?

Comment: http://netbeanside61.blogspot.ch/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, we do by Run -> Run Configurations -> Arguments tab: there you can specify the command line arguments. Hope, this won't differ much in NetBeans.